# Fetching all rows from a table where id repeats

Tags: php, mysql

```
+------+---------+----------+
| id   | uid     | assessors|
+------+---------+----------+
|    1 | 1       | Volvo    | 
|    2 | 2       | kenitra  | 
|    3 | 3       | rabat    |
|    4 | 3       | Fahad    |
|    5 | 3       | John     | 
+------+---------+----------+
```

I want to fetch the data on the base of uid because i use a Inner join to fetch data from other table now i want to fetch and show all assesors on uid but i get this output

```
+---------+----------+
| uid     | assessors|
| 1       | Volvo    | 
| 2       | kenitra  | 
| 3       | rabat    |
```

Desired Output is:

```
+---------+----------+
| uid     | assessors|
| 1       | Volvo    | 
| 2       | kenitra  | 
| 3       | rabat    |
| 3       | Fahad    |
| 3       | John     |
```

my query is =

```
SELECT * FROM lego_activity_answers WHERE uid = $studentid;
```

$studentid comes from another table

Comment: So which of the above tables is `lego_activity_answers`

Comment: The desire output looks like the first table except the `id`.

Comment: If you are specifying a `uid = $studentid;` I dont see how you get that result. **So show the real query**

Comment: First table is lego_activity_answers

Comment: And what is in `$studentid`

Comment: yes i want to fetch the all the data with same uid and different uid

Comment: This is id i fetch from another table

Comment: Then remove the WHERE

Comment: i fetch data from another table named users now i want to fetch data from this table with same uids of users table my problem is that if there is uid 3 in  $studentid then only one record is fetched i want to fetch all records against uid 3

Comment: **then show us ALL the relevant code** _Or we can continue guessing until we get bored, which will happen very soon now_

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all data in the `lego_activity` table except for `id`, simply select the individual fields you want, instead of querying `*`

```
SELECT uid, assessors FROM lego_activity_answers WHERE uid = $studentid;
```

Comment: This is repeating rabat for 3 times

Comment: If you do the above query with uid = 3, the result should be rabat, Fahad, and John

Comment: I do it multiple times but the result is rabat repeated 3 times

Comment: This is the main problem i want to all names rabat, Fahad and John

Comment: The above query will do what you are asking for - if you have more requirements, or more code, include it your question...

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT uid ,assessors FROM lego_activity_answers where uid=$studentid;

( this may not perform well at all in large tables )